# How can I add a divisible function to this calculator program?

Tags: java, user-interface, calculator

So below I have a calculator function. I have the addition, subtraction, and multiplication working just fine. The actual computation is not the issue here. (Note: the computation is in a different class all together). I simply need to figure out how to make the "/" symbol show up on the calculator gui when I launch it.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;


/* This is the GUI class that visualize the calculator 
 * 
 * */
public class Calculator extends Application {

    private MyStack stack = new MyStack();
    private double font_size = 30; //by default the font size on the screen is 30

    /*The keyboard key values*/
    private static final String[][] key_values = {
              { "0", "=", "c", "<" },
              { "1", "2", "3", "-" },
              { "4", "5", "6", "*" },
              { "7", "8", "9", "+" },
              { "/"}

          };
    private Button btn[][] = new Button[5][5]; //all the key buttons
    TextField calculator_screen;  //the calculator screen



    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

      @Override public void start(Stage stage) {

         /*The outside layout*/
         final VBox layout = new VBox(30); //the size vertically

         /*The inside layout for keys or buttons*/
         TilePane keypad = new TilePane(); //even it is called keypad, it is a layout
         keypad.setVgap(7);
         keypad.setHgap(7); //set the gap between keys


        /*Create Calculator Screen */
        calculator_screen =  new TextField();
        calculator_screen.getStyleClass().add("screen1"); //set the style of the screen
        calculator_screen.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT); //make the screen in the center of the calculator
        calculator_screen.setEditable(false); //make sure the screen cannot be typed in manually
        calculator_screen.setPrefWidth(300); //set the width of the screen
        calculator_screen.setPrefHeight(30);
        calculator_screen.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", font_size));

        /*Create Calculator keyboard*/
        keypad.setPrefColumns(key_values[0].length); //set the preferred number of columns

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            btn[i][j] = new Button(key_values[i][j]);
            final int a = i;
            final int b = j;

            /*Add button event*/
            btn[i][j].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                    StackNode node = new StackNode(key_values[a][b]);


                    if(a == 0 && b == 2) //if the key is "c"
                    {
                        stack.clear();
                        calculator_screen.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 30));
                        font_size = 30;
                    }
                    else if(a == 0 && b == 3) //if the key is "b"
                        stack.pop();
                    else if (a == 0 && b == 1) // if the key is "="
                    {
                        stack.computeExp();
                    }
                    else
                        stack.push(node); //otherwise push the key into the list

                    String math_exp = stack.getAllNodeValues();

                    if(math_exp.length() * font_size > 1.2 * calculator_screen.getPrefWidth())
                    {
                        font_size /= 1.2;
                        calculator_screen.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", font_size));

                    }

                    calculator_screen.setText(math_exp);

                }
            }
            );  

            //Add special style for the "=" button
            if(a == 0 && b == 1)
                btn[i][j].getStyleClass().add("btnEqual");
            else if(a == 0 && b == 2)
                btn[i][j].getStyleClass().add("btnClear");
            else if(a == 0 && b == 3)
                btn[i][j].getStyleClass().add("btnBackspace");
            keypad.getChildren().add(btn[i][j]);

          }
        }

        /*Put the calculator screen and keypad into a VBox layout*/
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(calculator_screen, keypad);
        layout.getStyleClass().add("vbox1");
        calculator_screen.prefWidthProperty().bind(keypad.widthProperty());


        /*Show the window*/
        stage.setTitle("Calculator");
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();


      }

}
```

Comment: May not be the direct issue but should you use `.Equals` for string comparison instead of `==`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is only that you never go over the fifth column of your key_values array when creating your buttons in your for loop.

You should verify the length of each row and column while iterating to make sure you don

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < key_values.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < key_values[i].length; j++) {
        btn[i][j] = new Button(key_values[i][j]);
```

Instead of :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        btn[i][j] = new Button(key_values[i][j]);
```